# JBoss CLI restricted access rights

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, jboss-cli

I am able to obtain information about the current deployments on the JBoss Server via JBoss CLI. (deployment-info)

I can connect to the JBoss CLI directly from the ssh terminal or from an web interface (Management console).

By using the CLI there would be much more possible then querying the deployment info.

Does anybody know if it is possible to have an **user** which has **restricted or limited rights for the JBoss CLI**? 
So that this user has only rights to query the deployment information but nothing else, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can RBAC for JBoss instance and configure user with 'monitor' role. User with this role can only perform Read-only operation. Go through [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/RBAC)  for more details on RBAC